# dynamic panel body in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I have following html for a comment section:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  <br>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <strong>{{ comment.author.username }}</strong>
              <div class="text-muted">commented on: {{ comment.created|date:"Y/m/d" }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              {{ comment.content }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When I have text that is too long it just overflows at the moment like this.

[image]

How can I force line breaks when the text is too long for the comment box?

Comment: You can do this -  `.break-word { word-wrap: break-word;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.break-word {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**HTML**

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  <br>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <strong>{{ comment.author.username }}</strong>
              <div class="text-muted">commented on: {{ comment.created|date:"Y/m/d" }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p class="break-word">{{ comment.content }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/60/)**

Answer (score 1):

use this in yours style

```
.panel-body
{
word-break: break-all;
}
```